# $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-4x\frac{dy}{dx}+6y=3+20\sin ({\ln x})$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to show that the substitution $x=e^t$ transforms the differential equation $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-4x\frac{dy}{dx}+6y=3+20\sin ({\ln x})$$ into $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-5\frac{dy}{dt}+6y=3+20\sin t$$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It it really 5 in the second equation?

Comment: Yes. It's in the given question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$t=\log x,\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$ and $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dt}$$
similarly you could find for the $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dt}\bigg)$$
$$=-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx}$$
now the equation will become 
$$x^2(-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2})-4x(\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dt})+6y=3+20\sin ({t})$$
on simplifying further 
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-5\frac{dy}{dt}+6y=3+20\sin ({t})$$

Comment: But I couldn't get the 5. I got 4 instead.

Comment: That's why I asked if it is really 5! I guess the book is mistaken!

Comment: You must be right, if your approach is right @LuísaBorsato

Comment: I get -5 in the second equation.

Comment: @DougM how? Can you show it?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $x= e^t$, we have that $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} =  \frac{dy}{dx}e^t$ and $\sin(\ln x) = \sin(\ln e^t) = \sin (t)$

Answer (score 0):

By substituting $t=\ln{x}$ we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}$$ and
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dt})=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x})\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dt})=-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}(\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}-\frac{dy}{dt}),$$ or
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}-5\frac{dy}{dt}-6y=3+20\sin{t} .$$
Therefore, $y=A e^{2 t}+B e^{3 t}+\frac{1}{2}+2 \sin{t}+2\cos{t}$.

(Final solution is sum of homogenous solution $A e^{2 t}+B e^{3 t}$ and partial solution $\frac{1}{2}+2 \sin{t}+2\cos{t}$)

Answer (score 0):

$t = \ln x\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac 1x \frac{dy}{dt}\\
\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac {-1}{x^2} \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac 1x \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac {-1}{x^2} \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac 1{x^2} \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$

$x^2(\frac {-1}{x^2} \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac 1{x^2} \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}) - 4x(\frac 1x \frac{dy}{dt})+6 y = 3 + 20 \sin t\\
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - 5\frac{dy}{dt}+6 y = 3 + 20 \sin t$